# PHP syntax error when using wpdb update?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm not too good with PHP, so I'm having trouble with some code that is supposed to update the wp_posts table. The problem is that when I try to save it, WP deactivates the plugin saying there's a syntax error in the following bit of code:

```
global $wpdb;
$dbresult = $wpdb->update($wpdb->post, ['post_title' => 'Test Title', 'post_content' => 'Test Content', 'group_access' => $group_access, 'tag_list' => $tag_list], ['ID' => 12095])) :
if (false === $dbresult) {
    echo 'An error occurred wile updating...');$errors = $post_id->get_error_messages();
}
```

I believe it would work if I could figure out what the syntax error was.

Comment: On your second line you got a `)` too much and `:` should be a semicolon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were multiple errors. It should be fixed now.

```
global $wpdb;
$dbresult = $wpdb->update($wpdb->post, ['post_title' => 'Test Title', 'post_content' => 'Test Content', 'group_access' => $group_access, 'tag_list' => $tag_list], ['ID' => 12095]); // <- One ) to much, : but needed ;
if (false === $dbresult) {
    echo ('An error occurred while updating...'); // <- Missing (
    $errors = $post_id->get_error_messages();
}
```

Comment: A good answer explains what have been changed and what the errors was and not just a "copy/paste" solution.

Comment: *"echo ('An error occurred while updating...'); // <- Missing ("* - Although it does work, echo isn't  a function, it's a construct. The brackets aren't even needed.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Changes are described in comments in the code.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yes, look at the code comments. Yes, this certainly fixed the syntax problem. Thank you.